# How to recover from error creating bean with name 'agentConfiguration'?

Tags: bamboo

Why does the following error occur when I start a remote agent ?

Agent doesn't start and it keeps displaying this error

```
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 | [Fatal Error] :-1:-1: Premature end of file.
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 | Exiting due to fatal exception.
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 | java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 |       at com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.bootstrap.AgentRunner.run(AgentRunner.java:28)
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'agentConfiguration' defined in class path resource [applicationContextRemoteAgent.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.atlassian.bamboo.configuration.ConfigurationException: Could not load configuration file bamboo-agent.cfg.xml from /home/bamboo_path/bamboo-agent-home
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 |       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
...
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 |       at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.remote.RemoteAgent.start(RemoteAgent.java:68)
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 |       ... 6 more
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 | Caused by: com.atlassian.bamboo.configuration.ConfigurationException: Could not load configuration file bamboo-agent.cfg.xml from /home/bamboo_path/bamboo-agent-home
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 |       at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.remote.AgentConfiguration.initConfiguration(AgentConfiguration.java:101)
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 |       at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.remote.AgentConfiguration.init(AgentConfiguration.java:62)
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
...
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 |       ... 19 more
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 | Caused by: org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: Premature end of file.
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 |       at org.apache.commons.configuration.XMLConfiguration.load(XMLConfiguration.java:673)
```

I'm using Bamboo Server instance, 5.8.1
Agent is running on JDK 1.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from:

```
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 | Caused by: com.atlassian.bamboo.configuration.ConfigurationException: Could not load configuration file bamboo-agent.cfg.xml from /home/bamboo_path/bamboo-agent-home
INFO   | jvm 21   | 2015/10/20 12:12:27 |       at com.atlassian.bamboo.v2.build.agent.remote.AgentConfiguration.initConfiguration(AgentConfiguration.java:101)
```

File **bamboo-agent.cfg.xml** cannot be loaded. In this scenario I've discovered that the file was corrupted, making the agent hang on startup.

This file should be in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<configuration>
<buildWorkingDirectory>/home/bamboo_path/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir</buildWorkingDirectory>
<agentUuid>aaaaaaaa-bbbb-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa</agentUuid>
<agentDefinition>
<id>14221333</id>
<name>Java Compiler</name>
</agentDefinition>
</configuration>
```

What I've discovered is that when I delete the corrupted file, and start the agent again, It will start. However it will register as a new agent. Making all agent dedication or custom capability settings missing.

You can find the old agent's definition in bamboo administration panel

> https_//bamboo.myurl.com/admin/agent/viewAgent.action?agentId=1234567

Copy paste the name and agent ID to **bamboo-agent.cfg.xml** and start the agent.

Comment: even though this answer is old, it still works flawlessly. Even leaving the agentUudi out works

Comment: @spankmaster79 glad it was useful. :)